# Is perfmon in jemter analysing cpu utilisation of local machine or the server where application is hosted?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, cpu, perfmon

Just need to know that perfmon plugin which is used in jmeter tool, does it analyse cpu/memory, disk utilization of local machine or the server where application is hosted?

Because as a user when give IP and port, we give these details of the remote  machines when we perform load test.

Please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

[PerfMon Metrics Collector](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) fetches performance metrics from [ServerAgent(s)](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) via TCP or UDP. And it's up to you where you want to install the ServerAgent(s), on JMeter or Application Under Test side or both.

Normally ServerAgent(s) is/are installed on Application Under Test side, i.e. web servers, database servers, load balancers, etc. to measure the load on that end, however if you want to collect performance stats from load generators - feel free to install Server Agent(s) on JMeter machine(s).

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for comprehensive information on PerfMon installation and usage

Comment: can perfmon in jmeter be used to collect performance metric data like memory, disk for SQL (i.e for database )

Comment: It has `exec` metric, using it you can execute arbitrary command, PerfMon will collect and plot the result

Answer (score 0):

As per JMeter Scientist,

> The **PerfMon** listener was implemented in following way: The
>   **Host** collects PerfMon, **Remote** nodes don't collect PerfMon.

So, Master will collect metrics from the Slaves.

[This might help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/uohk5wxYIbE)